# js .html() notification window disappears after first successful trigger

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I got a problem in my JS code, please look into it and suggest about what could be wrong.

In my html page I have a "div" as `<div id="notification"></div>` 
this "div" is the place where I want to display different kind of notification which might come after PHP code (e.g., kept in "myphppage.php") executed successfully.

```
<div class="cycle">
  <input value="Add to Cart" onclick="addToCart('828');" class="button" type="button">
</div>
```

Here is the javascript which is being triggered after onclick of a button:

```js
function addToCart(quantity) {

 $.ajax({
   url: 'myphppage.php',
   type: 'post',
   data: '&quantity=' + quantity,
   dataType: 'html',
   success: function(html) {

     if (html == 'success') {

       $('#notification').html('Success: Book added in your cart.' + '<img src="/img/close.png" class="close" />').show();

       $('#notification').addClass('success');

       $('.success').fadeIn('slow');

     }
   }
 })
}
```

After the php code echo "success" the #notification is shown properly in webpage but on subsequent hit of 'Add to Cart' button, although the php code is being executed successfully in background and php code echo "success"  the #notification is not displaying anything.

As a workaround, if I refresh the webpage then it again works for one time and from next time it just vanishes.

Comment: I have added the submit event it is based on onClick which is anyway being triggered whenever clicked on webpage

Comment: Please chow the complete addToCart

Comment: I am little new to this formatting. Is that help in understanding now?

Comment: Try adding `console.log(html)` to see if it is the string `success` or something else

Answer (score 0):

Your `#notification` must have an inline css `display: none;` after you hide it. Then next time when you use `.show()` it won't work.
Try remove the `.show()` as it does the same thing as `.fadeIn()`.